# Get Namespace level cost in Kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

We want to fetch cost at namespace level in a K8S cluster Azure (AKS), we are using a tool called kubecost to get cost incurred by each namespace, kubecost is an efficient tool which provides these information. I have setup the secrets for kubecost to access the Rate API, so will the cost of resources be fetched based on our account or is it just a generic cost ? (from what i read its just a generic cost fetched from public azure doc)
Has anyone used it in AKS, or is there any better way to it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Kubecost and have found that it is best out there for namespace level cost reporting.

> Kubecost provides accurate Spot pricing using the AWS Spot Instance
> data feed. It can also assist with pod right-sizing. It tracks the
> declared requests for containers and provides recommendations based on
> usage. The included Grafana dashboards show you resource utilization
> in your cluster.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/how-to-track-costs-in-multi-tenant-amazon-eks-clusters-using-kubecost/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-data-feeds.html